# Find occurence of a word in a sentence

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to find the occurence of a certain word in a sentence and then remove it. I'm able to do it but sometimes the word I wanna remove can be a subword. For example I wanna find/remove the word "word" in the sentence "Music is worldwide". My program will fin/remove return a positive value that it found the word "word" in the sentence while in fact it encountered the word "worldwide" and I would like it to return a negative value.
I'm currently using

```html
index = text.find(word)
```

Is there any other way to avoid this problem of the word being a subword in a sentence ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular expression module, and rely on regular expression word boundaries (`\b`) to only match the complete word.

Since you're trying to remove the word from the sentence, here's an example that replaces all the matches with an empty string:

```
import re

sentence = 'Music world is worldwide'
word = 'world'
removed = re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % word, '', sentence)

print removed # prints "Music   is worldwide"
```

If you just want to find the position of the first occurrence, you can do it as follows:

```
import re

sentence = 'Music is worldwide in the world'
word = 'world'
match = re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word, sentence)

if match:
    print match.start() # prints 26
```

Check the documentation of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for details.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of adding a space to the word i.e :

```html
word = " "+ word
index = text.find(word)
```

but I wonder if there's a more effective and clean way to do it.